# Using DRF FlexFields on Extra Actions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to use flexfields on viewset extra action

**serializers.py**

```
class FarmSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Farm
        fields = [
            'id',
            ...
            'varieties',
            'conditions',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
            'created_by'
        ]
        expandable_fields = {
            'varieties': ('labels.serializers.VarietySerializer', {'many': True}),
            'conditions': ('labels.serializers.ConditionSerializer', {'many': True}),
        }
```

**views.py**

```
class GrowerViewSet(BaseViewSet):
    ...
    serializer_class = GrowerSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=['GET'])
    def farms(self, request, pk=None):
        ...
        serializer = FarmSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Then, when I request `http://localhost:5000/api/labels/grower/3/farms/?expand=varieties,conditions` flexfield expand params dont work:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to add request context to Serializer

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['GET'])
    def farms(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Farm.objects.filter(grower_id=pk)
        serializer = FarmSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={"request": request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```